# Spring Rest как передать данные в указанное представление?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

Может быть я чего-то не понимаю...
Я пытаюсь сделать Spring Restful приложение
Вот мой контроллер, например:

```
public StudentDto saveStudent(@RequestBody StudentDto studentDto) {
        StudentDto savedStudent = studentsServices.saveStudent(studentDto);
        return savedStudent;
    }
```

Как мне теперь в .html файле получить объект savedStudent???
Класс контроллера помечен как @RestController
P.S. Если предлагаете вариант без использования RestController, тогда дайте пример как в функцию принять объект. Спасибо

Comment: Так вы же отправляете запрос с фронта на сервер, в чем проблема результат запроса отобразить в html файле?

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас есть какой-нибудь index.html в чистом HTML, то напрямую - никак. Можно использовать jQuery, посылать запросы через Ajax и получать ответы. Ответы у Вас будут приходить в JSON формате и их можно обработать.

Но, наверное, интересует все таки использование объекта внутри кода НТML, тогда используйте шаблонизаторы, например, spring thymeleaf, передавая параметры в модель...

Comment: Спасибо, @Антоша
Как я понял спустя 10 часов гуглешки это то, что мне поможет аннотация '@MdelAttribute', чтобы принять данные в метод, ну и вернуть необходимо представление при этом используя аннотацию '@Controller', а не '@RestController'